# Problema ao gravar valores em arquivo .CSV com linguagem C

Tags: c

Alguém poderia me ajudar por favor?

Estou iniciando o estudo na linguagem C e tenho o código abaixo que recebe valores nas variáveis da struct e grava em um arquivo .CSV, até ai está ok.
O problema que está gravando o valor da primeira variável na primeira linha e coluna do .CSV e os demais valores na segunda linha (de forma errada) e colunas corretas.

Busquei algumas alternativas mas mas não encontrei por aqui ainda, o que estou tentando fazer é com que todos os valores de input do user sejam gravados todos na primeira linha cada um em uma coluna no .CSV.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

struct dados {
    char nome[46];
    char cpf[12];
    char telefone[12];
    char email[51];
}; struct dados registro[6];

int main() {

    char c;
    FILE *file = fopen("3346941.csv", "w");

    printf("REGISTRO DE DADOS: \n\n");

    // fprintf(file, "%s;%s;%s;%s", "Nome", "CPF", "Telefone", "Email");

    printf("Digite um nome: ");
    fgets(registro[0].nome, 45, stdin);
    while ((c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF) {}

    printf("\nDigite um CPF (somente numeros): ");
    fgets(registro[1].cpf, 11, stdin);
    while ((c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF) {}

    printf("\nDigite um telefone (somente numeros): ");
    fgets(registro[2].telefone, 11, stdin);
    while ((c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF) {}

    printf("\nDigite um email: ");
    fgets(registro[3].email, 50, stdin);
    while ((c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF) {}
    
    fprintf(file, "%s;%s;%s;%s", registro[0].nome, registro[1].cpf, registro[2].telefone, registro[3].email);
    fclose(file);

    return 0;
}
```

Está salvando dessa forma:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Preciso que ficasse assim mas não consegui ajustar ainda:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui resolver o problema da quebra de linha do valor do primeiro vetor quando ia para o .CSV após algumas pesquisa do motivo que estava ocorrendo isso, identifiquei que era o último caractere que estava indo como uma linha nova, foi necessário que eu removesse o removesse da string com a função `strtok`.

Dessa forma quando a string é gravada no arquivo .CSV fica na mesma linha dos demais vetores da forma que eu estava necessitando.

```
char *name_adjusted;

name_adjusted = register_data[0].name; 
strtok(name_adjusted, "\n");
```